# converter nvarchar em bit C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

boa noite!

sua novo na linguagem C#

gostaria de saber como converto nvarchar em bit

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Falha ao converter o nvarchar valor 'Pagamento Pontual' para o tipo de dados bit.'

```
strSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm22", checkbox_pg_pontual.Text);
```

Comment: Use: `Boolean.Parse(checkbox_pg_pontual.Text)`.

Comment: tentei por, só que ainda esta aparecendo System.FormatException: 'Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como Boolean válido.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coluna de dados do tipo `BIT` no SqlServer geralmente é usado para guardar variáveis do tipo `bool` ou `booleano` como são conhecidas, apesar de não armazenar `True` ou `False` e sim `0`, `1` ou `null` geralmente.

Quando passado os textos "True" ou "False" utilizando o SqlParams esta conversão é feita automaticamente.

Então não sei qual o texto está tentando converter na coluna de tipo `bit` mas tenha certeza que é um valor aceitável pelo tipo explícito da coluna.

Comment: eu sei, porem esta dando erro ainda System.FormatException: 'Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como Boolean válido.'

Comment: Como está sua cadeia de caracteres?